# Query returns null value for column, need to replace the null value with a value. I do not know how. Please help

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
SELECT COL1, DATE_END
        FROM TABLE1 
        WHERE COL1 IN('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
    ORDER BY 1;
```

is the query. and when executed it gives me

```
COL1   DATE_END
1                                  
2 
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

because in the table the records 1...12 have their date_end as null

and the query should be modified in a way that the output is

```
COL1  DATE_END    
1     12/31/9999
2     12/31/9999
3     12/31/9999
4     12/31/9999
5     12/31/9999
6     12/31/9999
7     12/31/9999
8     12/31/9999
9     12/31/9999
10    12/31/9999
11    12/31/9999
12    12/31/9999
```

I hope I am clear this time, as to what I was trying out

Please help me experts... Thanks in advance

I have used "----" as I did not know how to insert spaces in HTML

Answer (score 6):

Use the COALESCE function to replace the NULL values. I'm also not a big fan of using ordinal positions in the ORDER BY clause, so I changed that as well.

```
SELECT COL1, COALESCE(DATE_END, '12/31/9999') AS DATE_END
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE COL1 IN('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12') 
    ORDER BY COL1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COL1, COALESCE(DATE_END, '12-31-9999') FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 IN('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12') ORDER BY 1;
```